# how to put quote around a sentence

Tags: oracle

I have a column in my table called Additional_comments. This column is a free text field where people pretty much write sentences, so it looks like this:

| Additional_comments |
| --- |
| The client is in need of basic services, housing, and employment help; client is in need of financial help. Client is in the senior age-group. |

I want the sentence to appear like this - "The client is in need of basic services, housing,   and employment help; client is in need of financial help. Client is in the senior age-group."

This is what I have tried before:

```
Select '"'+additional_comments+'"' from table;
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this query to figure out how I can add double quotes around the sentence. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the quotes to your column

```sql
select '"' || additional_comments || '"' from your_table;
```